# How to loop through pandas dataframe and modify value under condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "col1": [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5]
    }
)
df
```

[image]

I want to add another column that says "last" if the value in col1 doesnt equal the value of col1 in the next row. This is how it should look like:

[image]

So far, I can create a column that contains True when if the value in col1 doesnt equal the value of col1 in the next row; and False otherwise:

```
df["last_row"] = df["col1"].shift(-1)
df['last'] = df["col1"] != df["last_row"]
df = df.drop(["last_row"], axis=1)
df
```

[image]

Now something like

```
df["last_row"] = df["col1"].shift(-1)
df['last'] = "last" if df["col1"] != df["last_row"]
df = df.drop(["last_row"], axis=1)
df
```

would be nice, but this is apparently the wrong syntax. How can I manage to do this?

---

Ultimatly, I also want to add numbers that indicate how many time a value appear before this while the last value is always marked with "last". It should look like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is another step in my development or if this requires a new approach. I read that if I want to loop through an array while modifying values, I should use apply(). However, I don't know how to include conditions in this. Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For what it's worth, it's generally not recommended to mix types (string and int in this case) in Pandas dataframes.  You lose out on a lot of performance that way.

Comment: For the first part, you're so close since you have constructed a boolean Series already. Construct an empty column, now you can do: `df['last'][df['col1'] != df['last_row']] = 'last'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

considering that the index is incremental, (1) `cuncount` each group, then take (2)`max` index inside each group and set the string

```
group = df.groupby('col1')

df['last'] = group.cumcount()
df.loc[group['last'].idxmax(), 'last'] = 'last'
#or df.loc[group.apply(lambda x: x.index.max()), 'last'] = 'last'


    col1    last
0   1   0
1   1   last
2   2   last
3   3   0
4   3   1
5   3   last
6   4   last
7   5   0
8   5   1
9   5   2
10  5   last
```

Comment: I made this the accepted answer as it was the most straight foreward to me. Thanks!

Comment: `type(df.last)` tells me that this column is a `method`. How do I convert it to a `pandas.core.series.Series` (like col1 is)?

Comment: @Julian He is a Series, try `type(df['last'])`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way. You can obtain a cumulative count based on whether or not the next value in `col1` is the same as that of the current row, defining a custom grouper, and taking the [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html). Then add `last` using a similar criteria using `df.shift`:

```
g = df.col1.ne(df.col1.shift(1)).cumsum()
df['update'] = df.groupby(g).cumcount()
ix = df[df.col1.ne(df.col1.shift(-1))].index
# Int64Index([1, 2, 5, 6, 10], dtype='int64')
df.loc[ix,'update'] = 'last'

 col1 update
0      1      0
1      1   last
2      2   last
3      3      0
4      3      1
5      3   last
6      4   last
7      5      0
8      5      1
9      5      2
10     5   last
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! As `g = df.col1`, line 1 can be deleted and line 2 be replaced by `df['update'] = df.groupby(df.col1).cumcount()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.shift` to find where things change. Then you can use `.where` to mask appropriately then `.fillna`

```
s = df.col1 != df.col1.shift(-1)
df['Update'] = df.groupby(s.cumsum().where(~s)).cumcount().where(~s).fillna('last')
```

#### Output:

```
    col1 Update
0      1      0
1      1   last
2      2   last
3      3      0
4      3      1
5      3   last
6      4   last
7      5      0
8      5      1
9      5      2
10     5   last
```

---

As an aside, `update` is a method of DataFrames, so you should avoid naming a column `'update'`

Comment: Works fine! What exactly does `where(~s)` do though?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution.

```
df['update'] = np.where(df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift(-1)), 'last', 0)
```